# Refresh Page with Status Code after Content was loaded

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am building a file manager with php. Every request is handled by a php script, i.e. also direct download paths will be pre-checked so I can prohibit certain downloads and also display other content.

My problem now is, any here comes stackoverflow into play, that I do not know any solution how I can prepare the download aka display the content first, then refresh the page once so I can send the file ... but without side effects.

Refreshing is not a problem of course, but no refreshing solution works so far. Refreshing by header() keeps my page from displaying any content, refreshing with  or javascript works regarding the display of the content, however, downloads with e.g. wget do not work anymore.

The problem in other words is:

Due to the prior content load a valid status code will be sent, thus programs like wget or curl will not follow the refresh, so it will not download the file, only the html.
To get the actual file with curl or wget you need to send http headers, however, the 3XX redirection status codes will need a value for Location. If header('Location: ..') is sent the website will not be displayed before the refresh.

A solution is required that sending appropriate status codes is possible and the content will still be loaded prior the file distribution.

One partially solution has been found with status code 206, which does not require a location value and still works with wget. curl actually does not. so maybe a better solution is still available?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: post the code you have so far

Comment: This should be done using client-side techniques i.e Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

What about the `<meta>` tag?

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" URL="http://your-url.com/redirect/">
```

Comment: This will prevent wget from downloading the intended file because it deems the displayed content, which is loaded prior to the distributed file, as the content.

Comment: Can you use curl to receive the file?

Comment: I have found a partially solution though, I am sending status code 206. wget does then wait for refresh and download the actual file. curl still does not, though.

Answer (score -1):

Write this statement after printing content and it will wait 5 seconds before redirecting

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://your-url.com/redirect/" />
```